# vb.net or PS script to past value to a program form...

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I have an older program I think was developed/complied using C++ that tracks sellable items we have. We enabled an option in the programs preferences that allows us to use an alternate sort field for reporting and inquiries. This field can contain any alpha/numeric value, but cannot be 'Blank' NULL.

However, when we enabled this feature, and we realize now we can’t un-enable it. Each item records (14,000+) now contain a "blank" NULL value for this field.  At this point none of our reports will run and we get an error indicating: "Alternate Sort value can't not be NULL" So it looks like I will need to manually enter a value in the 'blank' NULL field.

I have a text file with the values for each record in the same order as they are displayed on the entry grid in the program. The database is propitiatory and there are no db tools provided to us that will allow us to import the values directly.

Does anyone know of a way to use vb.net or a PS script to basically read a value from a text file and then paste it where the cursor is on the screen and then send an {ENTER Key}, and then repeat the process?
Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to undo the change of the index, or just restore the database (files) to a working Version?

Comment: So we did restore and it is back working as it use to work.  But on the flipside, we need this feature.  So when I make the change, I have to all in the process, which means all records need updated and we can't use the system while the changes are being made as it locks this table from being used while the changes are being made.  I'm searching options to make these changes the fastest way possible!!! when I do go to enable this feature.

Comment: Could you tell us some more about the application, or even better the database? What type of database is it? Is it a (set of) files? What is the extension / file type? What' the name of the application?

Comment: It is Pervasive SQL 11.31.  The issue is the table is marked read only for outside access such as ODBC / MS Access.  It seems that there is an owner name and password that is needed to write directly to the database.

Comment: Wouldn't the application need a password as well? Or is the table never written to? Are you sure you want to make changes to this table?

Comment: The program uses a user ID and password to get into it.  It's an inventory tracking program, the alter key is a usable field for the users so they can enter and sort by an alternate value such as color, size etc.  Yes I do need to make changes to this table, its no different then when we add or delete an item it write to this same table.

Comment: I would try to connect to the database using the credentials that the application is using and write an update query that updates the table directly. Be sure to create a backup before and to test the functionality after the update.

Comment: Yep tried that and it doesn't work.  I think whom ever the developer of the program is, is passing the owner name and password from within the code (we can't see it) each time there is a read/write being done to the table.  I am sure they are not passing the user and password we use to log in to the program.